# Send a String as JSON object from web api to the client

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

In my .Net Core (EF) WebApi in C# I have an object `Property` that contains a (string) property `Settings`.

```
var p = new Property(){ Settings = "{decimals: 2, color: 'red'}" }
```

As you can see, the string is not in a strict JSON format, so parsing on the client asks additional energy, I would like to spend on the **server** side.

**How should I configure that property that the EF returns me not a string, but a json object**, so, for the example above that would be the object like this:

```
{ 
  settings: {
    decimals: 2, 
    color: 'red'
  } 
}
```

and not

```
{ 
  settings: "{decimals: 2, color: 'red' }"
}
```

that I obtain actually...

Comment: It sounds to me like the task here really isn't related to Angular, or EF, or WebAPI - it's a matter of "how to I parse a string which isn't quite JSON". Is that the case? (If so, I'd suggest you focus your question more tightly, and show what you've already tried.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, is a question where to parse it, at what moment, on server side, shoud the property "Settings" be annotated or in another way to say to server to send the string as object

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree is not a question about angular, i removed the tag, this is the question about EF.

Comment: How is it really about Entity Framework though? The data is a string in the database, yes? I would expect the same solution to apply *however* you receive that string - whether it's from a database, a file or anything else. I wouldn't expect Entity Framework to start parsing not-quite-json for you. That's really an application concern IMO.

Comment: @JonSkeet is probably about to write a StringToJsonConverter on the server side and use it with the EF configuration

Comment: I'm still not sure why you'd want to tie it to the EF configuration, rather than just processing the data *after* receiving it from the database. I'm still talking about it being done server-side, but between "receiving from EF" and "sending to client". Aside from anything else, separating out the concerns like that will make testing etc simpler.

Comment: @serge  It is a not a free coders resource. Can you show what you have done already and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the keys in quotation marks as well:

```cs
var p = new Property(){ Settings = "{'decimals': 2, 'color': 'red'}" }
```

Or maybe try to parse the string to a json object.

Comment: I would like to keep the string as is, not to modify it, and to parse on the server side, don't know at what moment should I do it

Answer (score 0):

I would use the JObject class to create a JSON object out of it. Have a look [here](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jobject.htm)  for more details about the class.

Comment: at what moment should we use that parse on the server side?

Comment: I think this example will help you [link] (https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreatingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult YourApiEndpoint()
{
    var p = new Property() { Settings = "{decimals: 2, color: 'red'}" };
    var settings = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Settings>(p.Settings);
    return Ok(new
    {
        Settings = settings
    });
}

public class Settings
{
    public int Decimals { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

or in case you want to use the built-in serializer, use `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<>` instead of `JsonConvert`